# I can not get into posts in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Once I click the posts in django admin then this message pops up **ValueError at /admin/blog/post/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'27th June'** yes, I put wrong form of data in DateField. I wanted to remove this data. that's why I tried to get into posts in django admin. is there anyway to fix this problem?

```
models.py
class Post(models.Model):   

    flight_date = models.DateField(blank=False)
```

Comment: You are using SQLite (This is possible only in SQLite)? You will have to remove that yourself manually by writing SQL, as if you try querying with python you will always get an error.

Comment: **Please do not "update"** questions because a new problem comes up when you try someone else's answer. Keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; questions need to be about a specific question, consistently. Edit only in order to fix a *problem with asking the original question* (e.g. missing information, or if you accidentally misrepresented the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in SQLite dates are simply stored as strings, hence you can store any invalid date as long as it is a string in your column. But the cursor that is used will try to convert this date into a string, and at this level you will get an error. Hence you cannot resolve to using the ORM to solve this problem and must use SQL queries to solve this.

You can use a raw query from Django's shell (`python manage.py shell`) if you don't know how to open the database shell, the below snippet assumes that your app is named `test_app`, you will need to replace that with your own apps name:

```
from django.db import connection


with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE test_app_post SET flight_date='2021-05-27' WHERE flight_date='27th June'")
```

Comment: I followed your instruction but I got the above error message

Comment: @PeterKam did you not _indent_ the line `cursor.execute(...)`?...

Comment: I thought it was done automatically... anyway I did again and it was done thanks

Comment: @PeterKam that is a different problem, hence you should post a different question for that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I deleted all posts in django shell and now no problem at all. I am able to get into 'posts' in django admin. once again, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please go into Django shell via this command

python manage.py shell

then import model from models file and fire update query

Comment: Will not work, as it appears OP has manually added this entry in SQLite table. The database backend / cursor itself will try to convert a string to date and fail. Although a raw query might work if you mean that.

Comment: are you able into django-shell?

Comment: Can you tell me more precisely please? I followed your instruction. I went into shell. and ```` from blog.models import Post ```` I tried to call that specific object but I don't know how to do it. so I put Post.obejects.all() ... same error message came out

Comment: Abdul Aziz Barkat>> yes, I did put this data mamually on the website (local server). how could I fix this then?

Comment: Post.objects.count()  then there are 60. so I tried to do this p = Post.objects.get(pk=60) but same error mesage came out. How could delete this data??

Comment: in case you are using pycharm then easily you can visualize your SQLite database file and find your data(pk) which throws errors and fire below query:

Post.objects.get(pk=your_data_pk).delete()